# What is the difference between HMS Core ML Kit and HiAI?

Tags: android, kotlin, machine-learning, huawei-mobile-services, huawei-ml-kit

What is the difference between HMS Core ML Kit and HiAI ? I see the document in [HiAI](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/hiai) , and the Facial Recognition, Image Recognition, text recognize... and I also see text recognize in  [HMS Core ML kit](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/hms/huawei-mlkit), what should I use?

Comment: You are asking two questions here. It's a good practice to ask one question per entry. Additionally your second question "What should I use?" obviously lacks context -- what do you need to use it for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[HUAWEI HiAI](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/hiai) is completely on the device side, and does not depend on the processing of the cloud side. It integrates NPUs with software, and opens multiple APIs including facial recognition, image recognition, video processing, text recognition, and document processing. It depends on Huawei Kirin SoC.

[HUAWEI ML Kit](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/hms/huawei-mlkit) allows your apps to easily leverage Huawei's long-term proven expertise in machine learning to support diverse artificial intelligence (AI) applications throughout a wide range of industries, including text-related, language-related, image-related, and face/body-related services. It provides both on-device and on-cloud APIs. On-device APIs are blistering-fast, without requiring a network connection, and on-cloud APIs provide a high degree of accuracy with the benefit of powerful computing, and are best equipped for complex scenarios. ML Kit has the advantage of supporting all android devices with ARM architecture, and all features are provided globally.

If your application needs to use device-side and cloud-side capabilities, and supports all android devices, it is recommended that you use HUAWEI ML Kit.